# Error: Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a Flutter program with Firebase Realtime Database, and I have encountered an error. How can I solve this error? Please provide an answer.
I store static data in firebase.

**clothes_list_screen.dart:**

```
class _ClothesListScreenState extends State<ClothesListScreen> {
  final databaseReference =
      FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('clothes_data');

  setData() {
    databaseReference.child('1').set({
      'image': "${AppImage.image}image8.png",
      'title': "Roller Rabbits",
      'price': " \$129"
    });
    databaseReference.child('2').set({
      'image': "${AppImage.image}image10.png",
      'title': "Madewell Dress",
      'price': "\$229.5"
    });
    databaseReference.child('3').set({
      'image': "${AppImage.image}image11.png",
      'title': "Axeal Arigato ",
      'price': "\$35.01"
    });
    databaseReference.child('4').set({
      'image': "${AppImage.image}image12.png",
      'title': "Gia Arigato pent ",
      'price': "\$35.01"
    });
  }

  List<bool> isLikedList = List.filled(20, false);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [gridViewList()],
          ),
    );
  }

  Widget gridViewList() {
    return ScrollConfiguration(
      behavior: const ScrollBehavior().copyWith(overscroll: false),
      child: Expanded(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
          child: StreamBuilder(
              stream: databaseReference.onValue,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data!.snapshot.value != null) {
                  List<dynamic> list = snapshot.data!.snapshot.value as List;

                  return GridView.builder(
                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        mainAxisExtent: 230.h,
                        childAspectRatio: 5,
                        crossAxisCount: 2,
                        mainAxisSpacing: 26.h),
                    itemCount: list.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      if (list != null && list.isNotEmpty) {
                        final isLiked = isLikedList[index];
                        return GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {}
                          child: Column(children: [
                            Stack(children: [
                              Container(
                                height: 225.h,
                                width: 155.w,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    image: DecorationImage(
                                  image: AssetImage(list[index]['image']),
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                )),
                              ),
                              Positioned(
                                top: 179.5.h,
                                child: Container(
                                  height: 51.h,
                                  width: 155.w,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color:
                                        AppColor.grayColor3.withOpacity(0.74),
                                  ),
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                    child: Column(
                                      children: [
                                        AppText(
                                            text: list[index]['title'],
                                            textColor: AppColor.blackColor,
                                            fontSize: 12.sp,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                                        AppText(
                                            text: list[index]['price'],
                                            textColor: AppColor.blackColor,
                                            fontSize: 12.sp,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ]),
                          ]),
                        );
                      } else {
                        return const AppLoader();
                      }
                    },
                  );
                } else {
                  return const AppLoader();
                }
              }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is my DEBUG CONSOLE:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building:
The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("image")

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:38:5)
#1      _ClothesListScreenState.gridViewList.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:fashions/screens/clothes_list_screen.dart:165:62)
#2      SliverChildBuilderDelegate.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_delegate.dart:490:22)
```

If a seam error occurs, please display the title and price.

[Firebase Realtime Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrJM8.png)

Comment: I'm not really familiar with working with Firebase, but to me it looks like `clothes_data` is a map with keys "1", "2", "3", "4" and not actually a list. But then I would think it should fail already on `List<dynamic> list = snapshot.data!.snapshot.value as List;` and not on `list[index]['image']` so that's kinda weird